# Unable to find 404 error in application or IIS logs

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a .NET website which I received a couple complaints that the user got a 404 error. They accessed the site through a link in an email. I tried the link in the email and it worked fine.

I checked the IIS (6) log file, I found my hits, could not find the ones in question. It was fairly easy to look up in the IIS log file, as the URL was something like examplePage.aspx?lastname=Smith&ID=12345. I also checked the Application Log under Event Viewer, nothing there either. Is there a chance that I would not find these errors in either of these logs, and what might I assume happened for them to get the error?

**Error screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use LogParser to query all the logs and find all broken links (404). For that download and install: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659

and then you can run from a command line:

```
cd "\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2"
LogParser.exe -i:w3c "SELECT cs-uri-stem, sc-status, COUNT(*) as Hits FROM c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\*  WHERE sc-status='404' GROUP BY cs-uri-stem, sc-status ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc" -o:TSV

LogParser.exe -i:w3c "SELECT TOP 25 STRCAT(TO_STRING(sc-status), STRCAT('.', TO_STRING(sc-substatus))) As Status, COUNT(*) AS Hits FROM c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\*  GROUP BY Status  ORDER BY Status ASC" -o:TSV
```

That should let you find all errors and an overview of the status codes. (You can change the TSV to CSV or XML or other formats if preferred)

Make sure the folder matches the folder where your site is logging.

Other samples might be useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/03/25/analyze-your-iis-log-files-favorite-log-parser-queries.aspx